# Unable to remotely connect to Postgresql 9.5 instance

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, postgresql

I am struggling to connect to a remote Postgres 9.5 instance running on Ubuntu 16.10.
The usual:

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
>     Is the server
>   running on host "xx.xx.xx.xx" and accepting   TCP/IP connections on
>   port 5432?

My postgresql.conf includes

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

confirmed by output from

```
netstat -nlp | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22981/postgres      
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      22981/postgres      
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3320886  22981/postgres       /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Apart from my specific IP address & range, I have also tried the following entries in pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5                                                                                                                                                                                       
host    all             all             ::/0                    md5
host    all             all             all                     md5
host    all             all             *                       md5
```

I have disabled ufw and flushed all iptables rules:

```
iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Scanning with nmap from my workstation:

```
nmap xx.xx.xx.xx -p5432

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-02-13 09:17 SAST
Nmap scan report for xx.xx.xx.xx
Host is up (0.0074s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5432/tcp filtered postgresql
```

telnet to xx.xx.xx.xx 5432 times out.

Almost all similar questions on SE seem to be solved with

> listen_addresses='*'

which is not an issue here.

Changing the port that Postgres listens on has no effect.

This is a dedicated server with public facing network interface.
The server has SSH & Nginx running, both of which are remotely accessible on the interface.

Really confused by this, help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

**EDIT:**
tcpdump output while attempting to psql & telnet into port 5432 using tcpdump switches suggested in comment:

```
tcpdump -i enp2s0 -s0 -XX -vv -n "tcp port 5432"
tcpdump: listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
2 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

*Ctrl-C after psql has timed out*

Comment: The port is shown as `filtered` in nmap output. Can you run `tcpdump` on your DB server to check whether you are receiving anything or not?

Comment: ran tcpdump - results above.
Does this mean that packets to port 5432 are filtered out before even getting to the network interface? (Please excuse, I'm a networking novice)

Comment: This isn't clear. Use `tcpdump -i enp2s0 -s0 -XX -vv -n "tcp port 5432"`. This will show packets with headers.

Comment: what about firewall & selinux?

Comment: selinux not installed, firewall explained above

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my hosting provider moved the server behind a managed firewall without notice.